# Python Text Widget - Displays Nothing on GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4, ttk

I am trying to populate 2 columns from my heap list into a text widget on my GUI. I have included my code below which does the same. self.top5 is my list which displays the first 5 elements sorted in descending order

```
self.tableSize = 25
self.hashTable = [[] for i in range(25)]
self.top5 = [(0,0) * 5]
```

After creating heap,validating hashkey,appending etc

```
self.top5 = (heapq.nlargest(5,heap)
self.text.tag_configure('big',foreground = '#5C0000',font('Verdana',9,'bold'))
self.text.tag_configure('sub',foreground = '#000000',font('Verdana',9,'bold'))
self.text.tag_configure('val',foreground = '#000000',font =('Verdana',9))
self.text.insert(INSERT,"\nEMP STATISTICS:",'big')
self.text.insert(END,"\n")
self.text.insert(INSERT,"EMP NUMBER:",'sub')
self.text.insert(END,"\t")
self.text.insert(INSERT,self.eID,'val')
self.text.insert(END,",")
self.text.insert(INSERT,"EMP NAME:",'sub')
self.text.insert(END,"\t")  
self.text.insert(INSERT,self.eName,'val')                
self.text.insert(END,",")

for k in self.top5:
        self.text.insert(INSERT,k[0],'val')
        self.text.insert(END, "\t\t")
        self.text.insert(INSERT,k[1],'val')
        self.text.insert(END,"\t\t\t")`
```

When i run my program, somehow nothing comes up on my screen. Though there is no error. Also, I am inserting first into my heapq and then fetching the top5 details sorted using nlargest.

Can someone please explain why am I not able to see any data on my GUI? When I use print statements at certain checkpoints, it works and I can definitely see proper output on terminal. I am a newbie, pardon me if it's too silly/obvious.

Comment: Are you placing the `self.text` anywhere? using either `.pack()` or `.grid()` or so?

Comment: Are you calling `mainloop()` somewhere? Do you have your own infinite loop that is preventing events from being processed?

Comment: OMG! @AnandSKumar , I  wasn't packing it! Thank you so much! Some how missed that piece of code... I can see the text widget on my screen now.. but somehow it doesn't auto-resize itself when I extend the screen... I tried the expand=1,fill='both'.. but that didn't help either. Its still the same.. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: @BryanOakley : Yes, I am. I wasn't using grid/pack. That's so silly! :-(..
How do I auto-resize the text widget size. Pack doesn't help..

Comment: @Dee: that's a completely different question that can't be answered in the comment area. pack (and grid) don't have any limitations with respect to auto-resizing, but it all depends on exactly how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure in order to display a GUI you need:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()          
root.title("YOUR TITLE HERE")
```

And then you need to use `pack()` after whatever you want to be displayed on the GUI and once that's done you need `root.mainloop()` to display the GUI altogether.